# Can the `erl -make` command be extended to do things other than compiling .erl files?

Tags: erlang, makefile, elixir, erl

I wanted to integrate Elixir into our project, and the good old codes don't use `rebar`, so I think writing the rules for building `.ex` files into `Emakefile` may be a good idea, yet the man page [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) didn't mention anything relevant.

Edit:

Our team works mainly in Windows environment, but the deployment will be done on Linux servers, so I need a cross-platform solution. Since Erlang itself is cross-platform, I wanted to do it with `erl -make` command.

Of course I can write a `Makefile`, but then I'll need a `build.bat` or something alike to build the code in our developing environments, since we don't have `make` command on our dev' machines.

Anyone have a better idea?

Update:

In case anyone wants to know, I'm doing it this way:

1. Copy the `lib/elixir` directory in the Elixir source tree to our source dir, say `some_project/src/tools/elixir`.
2. Add `some_project/src/tools/elixir/src/elixir_transform.erl` and `some_project/src/tools/elixir/src/*` to the `Emakefile`, in that order. Set the output dir to `some_project/ebin` (All the other `.beam` files are located there).
3. Copy `src/elixir.app.src` in the Elixir source tree to `some_project/ebin/elixir.app`, and edit it to fix the version code.
4. Build the Erlang code by running `erl -pa ebin -make`, in `some_project` dir.
5. Build the Elixir compiler by running `erl -pa ebin -s elixir_compiler core -s erlang halt`
6. Now we have a working Elixir environment in our code, and I use the following escript to build our custom `.ex` files:

> ```
> %%! -pa ./ebin
> main(_) ->
>     ExList = [ 
>         <<"source_1.ex">>,
>         <<"source_2.ex">>,
>         <<"source_3.ex">>],
>     application:start(elixir),
>     gen_server:call(elixir_code_server, {compiler_options, [{docs, true}, {debug_info, true}]}),
>     [elixir_compiler:file_to_path(F, <<"./ebin">>) || F <- ExList],
>     erlang:halt(0).
> ```

Comment: I think I may write a parse_transform and hook it up to a special empty module to do anything I want at compile-time, but that's kinda messy....

Comment: I used the Makefile-and-bat approach in the end, turns out it's not that bad....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to explicitly compile Elixir, I would go with the Makefile approach since it will always be supported by Elixir. However, I would recommend the precompiled binaries or even assume Elixir is installed in each developer machine. You can even add a task to your Emakefile to guarantee everyone is using the proper Elixir version.

Finally, about compiling your own Elixir code, I would recommend simply using `mix`. `mix` is a binary that ships with Elixir and you can simply do `./src/tools/elixir/bin/mix compile` from your `Emakefile`.

In case using mix is not possible, you should use the parallel compiler, since it will compile files using all cores available in your machine and it will automatically detect and solve dependency in between files. Here is an example of calling the parallel compiler from erlang:

https://github.com/basho/rebar/pull/347/files#L1R62

The API is very simple. It expects a list of file names to compile as binary and the directory to output files to as another binary.

Comment: Thanks! Somebody came up at last, and he's the creator of Elixir! +1 for the parallel compiler hint :)